# cancer diagnosis model has errors i am failing to understand

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, conv-neural-network

https://pastebin.com/GaR9TBTf

```
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/My Drive/scan_xray/chest_xray /test /',



 target_size = (224, 224),
batch_size = [32],
class_mode = 'categorical')

len(test_set)
```

failed to paste my code properly in this platform , my sample code and errors are in the pastebin, hoping its permitted to do so. lung cancer diagnosis model giving me errors.Any help necessary will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`batch_size = [32]`

To to replace it by

`bath_size = 32`

As the error says, it ask for an interger and not a list

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-7096870c5301> in <module>()
      7   epochs=50,
      8   steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
----> 9   validation_steps= len(testing_set)
     10 )

NameError: name 'testing_set' is not defined    (___this error comes up___)

Comment: Isn't it because your variable name is test_set and not testing_set ?